# Skype status button in user profile opening Skype app when button is clicked

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, users, hyperlinks, design

I tried adding a Skype button in my [StackOverflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114029/leniel-macaferi) to show my current status: online/away/offline using the code provided by Skype: http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/wizard/

The button works as expected showing my status, but if someone tries to click it, the Skype app won't open because this URL:

http://skype:lenielmacaferi?chat

is translated to:

```
http://skype:lenielmacaferi/?chat
```

With the above link, this window won't appear:

[image]

I also think that the URL should not have the http part. It should only be

```
href="skype:lenielmacaferi?chat"
```

but this is not possible as of today.

Would this be acceptable or even possible in the future? If there's security concerns, no problem... I'll just close this question. :)